# Trying to post an Array of Objects in Laravel. ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value in file

Tags: sql, laravel, post, eloquent, insert

I'm trying to send a POST request with a data set like this:

```
[
    {
    "Course_Code":"CIS341",
    "Start_Date":"2020-08-22",
    "End_Date":"2020-12-02",
    "CRN":345627,
    "CWID":"C38475920",
    "Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"
    },
    {
    "Course_Code":"CIS341",
    "Start_Date":"2020-08-22",
    "End_Date":"2020-12-02",
    "CRN":456392,
    "CWID":"C38475920",
    "Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"
    },
    {
    "Course_Code":"CIS341",
    "Start_Date":"2020-08-22",
    "End_Date":"2020-12-02",
    "CRN":562940,
    "CWID":"C38475920",
    "Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"
    }
]
```

**But I only want to insert the CRN, CWID, Date_Registered from each of those objects into my final_schedule table:**

```
protected $table ="final_schedule";
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = [
    'CWID',
    'CRN',
    'Date_Registered'
  ];
```

Here is the insert function I'm using:

```
public function insert(Request $request){
      $CWID->CWID = $request->input('CWID');
      $CRN->CRN = $request->input('CRN');
      $Date_Registered->Date_Registered = $request->input('Date_Registered');

      $items = array('CWID'=>$CWID, 'CRN'=>$CRN, 'Date_Registered'=>$Date_Registered);
      finalScheduleModel::insert($items);
    }
```

When I test this insert function in postman it gives the error: 
`ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value in file`
And the line the error is pointing to is the first line of the function 
`$CWID->CWID = $request->input('CWID');`
I tried writing this function many different ways, but I keep getting errors along the same lines. It never reads any of the data being sent over. It might say something like trying to insert values CWID, CRN, Date_Registered (?,?,?) into final_schedule.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to post an array of objects. I'm trying to make three new rows in my final_schedule table with the data above.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what you mean be expected shape.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this. I thought `finalScheduleModel::insert` was just another way to write this: `DB::table('final_schedule')->insert($items);`

Comment: Oh alright, thank you!

Comment: updated, please check my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this see if this works for you.

```php
public function insert(Request $request){
          $array = [];
    foreach (request()->all() as $value) {
        array_push($array, ['CWID' => $value['CWID'], 'CRN' => $value['CRN'], 'Date_Registered' => $value['Date_Registered']]);
    }

    DB::table('final_schedule')->insert($array);
    }
```

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `final_schedule` (`0`, `1`, `2`) values ({"CRN":345627,"CWID":"C38475920","Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"}, {"CRN":456392,"CWID":"C38475920","Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"}, {"CRN":562940,"CWID":"C38475920","Date_Registered":"2020-04-02"})) in file` Still throws an error but it actually recognizes the values being sent

Comment: Yes those are the only fields in the final_schedule table. CWID is varchar(9), CRN is int(11), and Date_Registered is a date value in the format YYYY/MM/DD. I didn't use a migration file, the DB was set up in phpmyadmin with a .sql file and I just connect to it. Sorry if that isn't helpful.

Comment: It has the same exact result sadly

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! This should also help me a lot with the update I have to do too, so thanks!